# C++ syntax name for this (exprA, exprB, exprC)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

std::string getMyName(void)
{
  std:: cout << "This is function getMyName" << std::endl;
  return std::string("hello world");
}

std::string getMyName2(void)
{
  std:: cout << "This is function getMyName2" << std::endl;
  return std::string("hello world2");
}

int main(void)
{
  // what is the official name for the following syntax?
  bool isDone = (getMyName(), getMyName2(), false);

  std:: cout << "isDone " << isDone << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

user@ubuntu:~/Documents/C++$ ./period 
This is function getMyName
This is function getMyName2
isDone 0
```

As you can see the following statement is evaluated from left to right and the value of `isDone` is assigned with the last expression of value `false`.

```
bool isDone = (getMyName(), getMyName2(), false);
```

I would like to know the official syntax name for this statement. I have searched 'period statement' through G and without meaningful hits.

Thank you

Comment: As a note, I wouldn't use code like this.  As a rule of thumb, you normally don't want to do an assignment operator that has side effects.  You may know that `getMyName()` has side effects, but someone else may not.  It'd be better to do something like what @JaredPar suggested.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are making use of the comma operator

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

This operator will evaluate the left expression first, then evaluate the second and use it's result as the result of the expression.  It's roughly equivalent to

```
getMyName();
getMyName2();
bool isDone = false;
```

Comment: How can I search with 'period statement'? Damn！